# How do I process only checked rows in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming I have the following table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"/> A2</td>
      <td>A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"/> B2</td>
      <td>B3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C1</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"/> C2</td>
      <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to generate JSON from the table only for the rows whose checkbox is checked. What do I put in for "Insert Check Here"?

```
var myRows = [];
var $headers = $("th");
var $rows = $("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
  $cells = $(this).find("td");
  myRows[index] = {};
  $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
    // Insert Check Here
    myRows[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).html();
  });    
});

var myObj = {};
myObj.myrows = myRows;
alert(JSON.stringify(myObj));​
```

Comment: you only have one row with checkboxes in it. Perhaps you are looking to serialize checked columns?

Comment: My bad, its one column. Modified question to reflect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added an If statement to test if the TD contains a checkbox which is checked or not, see the comment in the code

```
// Loop through grabbing everything
    var myRows = [];
    var $headers = $("th");
    var $rows = $("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
      $cells = $(this).find("td");
      myRows[index] = {};
      $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
         if($(this).find('checkbox').is(':checked')) //Find the checkbox within the TD and test if it's checked or not
         {
           myRows[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).html();
         }
      });    
    });

// Let's put this in the object like you want and convert to JSON (Note: jQuery will also do this for you on the Ajax request)
var myObj = {};
myObj.myrows = myRows;
alert(JSON.stringify(myObj));​
```

Comment: the myRows variable appears to be empty with the addition of the check in the alert box that pops up.

Comment: I saw your commented code and presumed the rest was working, hence why i only added the `if` statement as you asked. Please see some of the other answers below which generally show a much simpler way of solving this task.

Comment: The code I posted works as is, but returns contents every row in the table (does not check for whether the row has a checkbox). Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
var selectedRowsHTML = "";

$('table input:checked').each(function() {
  selectedRowsHTML += $(this).closest('tr').html();
});

console.log("This is the HTML for selected rows: "+ selectedRowsHTML);
```

With ":checked" selector you get only inputs that are checked inside your table. Iterate over them, finding the parent row with "closest('tr')". And that's all, you get the HTML for every row (or whatever you want to do with them).

Answer (score 0):

how about thus

```
$("table input:checked")  //filter based on your requirement
.each(function()
{
  var td=$(this).parent();  //gets the `td`, do the necessary
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the checkbox:checked selector and closest to find the nearest element of a specific type.

```
var selectedRows = [];
$('table input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
  selectedRows.push($(this).closest('tr'))
});
```

selectedRows contains an array of the selected table rows